# Finding closest 3 Points from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, coordinates

I have an `ArrayList<Vector2> map` which contains various two dimensional coordinates. Normally fewer than 10.

Given a `Vector2` object as argument, what is the best way of find the three closest `Vector2`s in the `ArrayList` and shoving them into `Vector2[] closest`? The order of the elements of Vector2[] does not matter.

**PS:** The Vector2 class mentioned above is the one used in AndEngine Box2D extension. If unfamiliar with it, think of it as a pair of `float`. Conveniently it has the `someCoordinate.dst(someOtherCoordinate)` to get the distence between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already have the `dst()` function to get the distance between two `Vector2` objects, why can't you just do a `for` loop getting the distance to every other object in the ArrayList?

You could create much more complex structures: dividing the Vector2 objects by the position in a imaginary grid, so you first can find the closet area and check only against those Vector2 objects in that area. But sincerely, if you are managing just 10 objects, it is not worth the effort. You won't win any performance, and you will have to create that `for` loop anyway.

**Loop example (as asked for in a comment):**

I assume we already have `Vector2 myVecky` and `ArrayList<Vector2> map`.
I may do some mistake, as I'm not compiling this. But it should be good enough to take on from.

```
Vector2 closestVecky = null;
float shortestDistance = -1;
for (Vector2 vecky : map){
    float veckyDist = vecky.dst();
    if (closestVecky==null || veckyDist < shortestDistance){
        shortestDistance = veckyDist;
        closestVecky = vecky;
    }
}
//when you reach here, you will have your `closestVecky` and `shortestDistance`
```

Comment: looping through each element to get the distance was how I decided to attack this to begin with, however, temporarily storing the highest distance:object pairs is what is making me scratch my head. Some code example would be useful. Sorry I can't brain today, I have the dumb.

Comment: I added some sample code for your loop. You owe me one beer